# FileNotFoundException for System.ServiceModel.Primitives, when using Reflection on a .NET Core DLL that contains a connected service reference.,

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, .net-core, code-generation

I have a .NET Core DLL project that uses a Connected Service to reference a popular SOAP API. Accessing the SOAP API and all it's functionality works fine.

On this project, I have a [Scripty](https://github.com/daveaglick/Scripty) .csx script file that is loading the already built DLL and iterating through the types it exposes. The code looks something like below

```
var assemblyPath = Path.Combine("fullPathTo.dll");
if (!File.Exists(assemblyPath)) return;

var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
if (assembly != null)
{
    Output.WriteLine("// " + assembly.FullName);
    try
    {
        foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            Output.WriteLine("// " + type.FullName);
        }
    }
    catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
    {
        Output.WriteLine($"/* {string.Join<Exception>("\r\n", e.LoaderExceptions)} */ ");
    }
```

The assembly loading works just fine but the line for `assembly.GetTypes` fails with the following exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I have tried adding a nuget reference to System.ServiceModel.Primitives (tired with v4.3.0 and 4.1.0 which are the versions available). But, I continue to get this error. What else can I try?

Comment: Did you have any luck solvinh this

Comment: @NikolaGaić Sorry, no. I was having this issue using Scripty for code generation. I stopped using Scripty and switched to RazorLight which has worked out just fine for my requirements.